# Qt 5 статические библиотеки

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Собрался попробовать использовать Qt 5.9.1, совместно с библиотеками `libvlc`.

Но тут меня ждала неудача, пытаюсь подключить библиотеки через
`#pragma comment(lib "...")`

Но тут становится понятно, что нужно как-то по другому линковать, нашел, но снова не идет, не могу понять в чем проблема, библиотеки лежат прямо в директории с исходниками, но получаю ошибку

`:-1: ошибка: LNK1104: не удается открыть файл "libvlc.lib"`

Файл pro:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2017-08-18T18:30:23
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui widgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = AnimeWatch
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += "./"

LIBS += -L"./" -llibvlc -llibvlccore
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Возможно лучше указать вот так:

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD -lvlc -lvlccore
```

$$PWD - каталог, в котором находится pro файл

Comment: Ваш вариант частично помог, точнее да, он теперь находит библиотеки, но не линкуется на них. 9 неразрешенных символов, что свидетельствует о том что он все таки не слинковался.

Answer (score 0):

Префикс `lib` автоматически добавляется компилятором gcc. Уберите его.

```
LIBS += -L"./" -lvlc -lvlccore
```

Answer (score 0):

Задайте библиотеки так:

```
LIBS += -L./ -lvlc -lvlccore
```